# Solving Holoeverywhere 1.4 migration errors

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

Due to some bugs I updated the Holoeverywhere library to 1.4 and ActionbarSherlock to 4.4.
I (hopefully) resolved the support jar mismatch error and ASB and HoloEverywhere compile fine against Android 4.2. ABS is a library of HoloEverywhere and HoloEverywhere is a library of my application.

After changing the source according to the [Migration Doc](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Migration-on-1.4) (e.g. using org.holoeverywhere.activity instead of SActivity) there are still some errors left and I would like to know if the implementation changed or I am missing imports or something.

Some errors are:

```
import org.holoeverywhere.app.Dialog;
import org.holoeverywhere.app.ListActivity;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

// Cannot override the final method from _HoloActivity
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    }

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.context_menu_dialog_title);

    menu.add(0, CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE, 13, R.string.context_menu_delete);
}
// The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined 
...
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
...

// The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_save_cancel, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
That fixed most onContextItem errors.

What about

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
}
```

and

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
}
```

Comment: For the first error: In `onContextItemSelected` you should use `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem` typed parameter instead of `android.view.MenuItem`.